# request for member n something not a structure or union

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct spi_device device_t;

struct spi_device {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
```

defined in include file.

And in source file,

```
static device_t my_main_dev = 
{
  .a = 2,
  .b = 3,
  .c = 4,    
};
```

I have made sure that the include file is included in the source file.

But when I compiled this code I am getting the error 'request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union'. I am not able to rectify this issue.

I have read few posts which talk about this problem, but none of them say what we can do when we face an error during initialization of structure object. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: What are your compilation flags? In particular, are your compiling as c99 or newer?

Comment: There are no particular compiler flags. I am using default options. I am just providing "-ggdb -Wall -Werror" options.

Comment: Try adding `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly bug. I had missed a comma for one of the fields. Putting it back resolved the compiler error. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a compilable source file that exhibits the problem. The diagnostic might pertain to some other part of your source file than what you posted.

If the warning really points to the posted code, here are some possible explanations:

- your compiler does not support C99 extensions. These are quite rare today, but some old compilers targeting the embedded processors are clunky and like old monkeys, cannot be taught new tricks.
- your compiler is configured to reject c99 extensions (with `-std=c89` or `-ansi`).

To work around these limitations, you can use the classic syntax for structure initializers:

```
static device_t my_main_dev = { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: it is hard to find such a compiler nowadays. Even gcc 4.6 supports it by default. https://godbolt.org/z/Z9XbaQ

Comment: @P__J__: of course modern compilers have supported this syntax for quite a while... I updated my answer with more possibilities